# How do we use a multi byte field delimiter in a file format

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are trying to create a file format using the not character ¬ as the delimiter.  We can't get Snowflake to work with a file delimited in this format.  The documentation says multibyte delimiters are now supported.  We've tried:

- Just typing ¬ in  the file format dialog
- The hex code (permutations of 0xC2AC , 0xC20xAC etc)
- The octal code 302 254 entered as permutations of \302254 etc

But whatever we try we get errors.  Typing the delimiter straight it seems to think 0xC2 is the delimited and it gets confused by the second byte (0xAC).  Using hex code or octal code gives an error about wrong number of columns.  Any advice please?

Comment: For octal format use \302\254, see example [**here**](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-use-the-Thorn-delimiter-in-the-file-format)

Comment: Can you share a sample file to test the solution?

Comment: Thanks @Sergiu that worked perfectly, must be the only thing I didn't try!

Answer (score 1):

Answer from Sergiu works perfectly:

For octal format use \302\254